# Cordova how to play StreamURL

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic2, video-streaming

Here is my URL

http://came3.nkansai.ne.jp:81/nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Motion

I am using ionic 2.

I need to play this video.

I have no idea.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript in Cordova you can use a JQuery plugin like this one: https://github.com/clipchamp/jquery-clipchamp-mjpeg-player-plugin , assuming you want it to work more like a video.

Alternatively, you can also just embed it as an image like this:

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="http://came3.nkansai.ne.jp:81/nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=640x480&amp;Quality=Motion">
```

However, you would get no controls in this case. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.It's work fine.I have one doubt.How can i stop video.and again play video using streaming URL.Can u help me..